# facebook application ignores unload event

Tags: javascript

I want to open a dialog in facebook app during page unload (leave this page or stay on this page) and if user clicks "leave this page" it calls a function 
I have tried to open dialog onbeforeunload and call function on unload but unload function was ignored in facebook application (everywhere else it works fine)

```
function setHandler() {
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are You Sure ?";
  };
  window.addEventListener("unload", function(){
    // call some function
  }, false)
}
window.onload=setHandler();
```

Comment: Please phrase your question in the form of a question. It's funny because I'm finding this more than 10 years later, but I'm having the same question. Why doesn't unload event fire from the Facebook app. I'm specifically trying to get what time Facebook ad visitors bounce after arriving at the site.